# Ruby: Difference between these two?

Tags: ruby, printing, coding-style

I was wondering what the difference between `print x` and `print "#{x}"`, in Ruby was. Does it really matter which one we use?

Comment: Do you understand what the `#{}` syntax does in the general case?

Answer (score 1):

`print "#{foo}"`  - here you are doing string interpolation.Whatever object will be referenced by `foo`(if it is a local variable), returned from `foo`(if it is a method), on that result `String#to_s` will be applied.

`print foo` will output the object will be referenced by `foo`(if it is a local variable), returned from `foo`(if it is a method), on that result `#to_s` will be applied.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `print "#{foo}"` roughly translates to `print foo.to_s`.

[`Kernel#print`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-print) is a thin wrapper around [`IO#print`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-i-print) which ultimatively calls [`IO#write`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-i-write). From `write`'s documentation:

> [...] If the argument is not a string, it will be converted to a string using `to_s`. [...]

So in the end, there is close to no difference. `print "#{foo}"` will however first create a String representation of `foo` and secondly interpolate that result into an otherwise empty string—but I think that could (should) easily be optimized by the interpreter.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind, if you come back and do something more to the output, the string interpolation route can be more attractive.

    print "this: #{foo}"

is a bit easier to read than

    print "this " + foo.to_s

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference, they both apply `to_s` implicitly at some point. You should use `print x` and not `print "#{x}"`. Why would you wonder which to use? `print "#{x}"` is obviously less simple than `print x`.

Answer (score 0):

The `print name` is usually used if you only need to print that thing and nothing more.

String interpolation is used when you want to insert the values in other strings.

```
print "My name is #{my_name} and I am currently #{my_age} years old."
```

It is even possible to insert some logic:

```
print "My name is #{my_name.capitalize} and"
print "I am currently #{my_age} year#{my_age>1 ? 's':''} old." #print years instead of year if age is greater than 1.
```